# C# WinForm - Keypress and Show The Value From Database Column Base On The Input Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using C# Window Form.

This is the scenario.

I have a text field where the user can type the words/letters connected to the database column of names. When the user type the words/letters, then drop down will automatically showing the names saved in the column of names inside my database. When I click the name that matches my input text, I can click it and automatically fill the text field with my chosen name.

```
txt_names.Text // The name of my textfield.

private void txt_names_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // I have no codes here.
}
```

Probably the best way to do that is using keypress or keydown whatever. Any idea how can capture the names inside the database. Its like ajax something but in C# Window Form.

Any help? Please drop your answers/comments below. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will help you, create a method in this case mine is **AutoCompleteTxtBox()**

```
 void AutoCompleteTxtBox() 
    {
        txt_names.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        txt_names.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection coll = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = "your connection string";
        conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from your DataBase table name";
        OleDbDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (myReader.Read())
        {
            string lname = myReader["the column name you want to autocomplete"].ToString();
            coll.Add(lname);
        }

        txt_names.AutoCompleteCustomSource = coll;
        conn.Close();
    }
```

then call the method on that form where you have **InitializeComponent() method** like this

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AutoCompleteTxtBox();        

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using combobox control. Just populate it with a list of strings.

And turn on autocomplete option.